# No module named html2text

Tags: python, ipython

I have tried various ways to install the library html2text and all end with ipython not being able in import it with the error message

> "ImportError: No module named html2text"

```
The directory '/Users/NDunn/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent  directory is not
 owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled.
 Please check the permissions and owner of that directory.
 If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/NDunn/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned
by the current user and the cache has been disabled.
Please check the permissions and owner of that directory.
If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting html2text
Installing collected packages: html2text
Successfully installed html2text-2015.6.21
```

I have used `sudo` and `-H` sudo both of which say it has installed but then I can not import.

Any ideas on what is going on would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you've installed it for the same interpreter you're trying to import it into?

Comment: What various ways? What version of python? What version of ipython?

Comment: Start with `which ipython` to find out to which interpreter ipython belongs. After that use `<path/to/interpreter>/python -m pip` to install your module.

Comment: python ver.2.7.6
ipython ver.3.2.1

basically pip and easy_install. When it is installed it is found in usr/local/bin, along with python and ipython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. It turns out that IPython did not have a path to the location of where pip was placing new libraries. To test this use 'pip show html2text'(or any library you want to import to IPython), look to see it's location. Should look something like this.

```
location :/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Open IPython and run 'import sys', then run 'sys.path'. If you do not see the prior location in the list then you need to append it to the list.

Navigate to where you installed IPython and then to its profile. Path should look something like this.

```
~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/
```

Inside create a file '00-startup.py', once done edit the file so that the first line reads 'import sys' and then below that 'sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')'. This is my example so change the path appropriately.

```
import sys 
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
```

Save the file and now it should hopefully work.

Answer (score 7):

In my case(ubuntu14) it has worked just with following command:

```
sudo python -m pip install html2text 
html2text installed successfully.
```

Comment: This fixed my issues with Mac on Python2.7 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays many systems come with multiple versions of python and therefore there can also be multiple versions of `IPython`.

When using `pip install <package>` it's not immediately clear to which interpreter the package will be belong in the end.

So how do we find out? Since unix based systems come with a very powerful shell we can use it to solve the problem:

`which -a` will list all `ipython` executables that are in your `PATH`. The first one will be called when you type `ipython` into your shell.

For me it's just:
`which -a ipython` -> `/Users/ch/miniconda/envs/sb34/bin/ipython`

Now we know that the standard `ipython` belongs to the interpreter `/Users/ch/miniconda/envs/sb34/bin/python`. So instead of calling `pip install html2text`, we can now use

```
/Users/ch/miniconda/envs/sb34/bin/python -m pip install html2text
```

to make sure that `html2text` is installed into the interpreter that also contains the default `ipython` executable in `PATH`.

Depending on the path and your user privileges, you may have to use `sudo` to gain sufficient writing permissions.

Comment: Thanks for a great explanation. I tried it out and am still getting this message.

The directory '/Users/NDunn/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled.

Comment: @Wine.Merchant, See if the option `--no-cache-dir` is a workaround. If it is not, consider adding the full error traceback to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have few versions of `Python` installed, use `sudo pip install --target=path/to/your/pythonXX/site-packages html2text` and then package will be available for certain Python interpreter. And then use `import html2text` in your code editor/Python shell

Comment: using `target` is much more error prone, than invoking the right pip version in the first place.

Comment: sudo pip install --target=path/usr/local/bin/python2.7/site-packages html2text

Caused an exception.

Comment: @Wine.Merchant without word "path"- just `sudo pip install --target=/usr/local/bin/python2.7/site-packages html2text`

Comment: So this is the end of the exception thrown.

 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 264, in finalize_options
    "must supply either home or prefix/exec-prefix -- not both"
DistutilsOptionError: must supply either home or prefix/exec-prefix -- not both